# Python selector.select returning empty socket as readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selector, httpserver

I'm having problems implementing a basic HTTPServer in Python 3.6 on windows 10 Pro x64.

Essentially the selector being used in the base implementation of `socketserver.serve_forever()` uses a selector to determine if a socket is readable.  The issue is that after a single GET request is received by the server it always evaluates true.  So lets take the scenario where a single GET request is received.  The GET is handled, the socket is flushed, but `selector.select` returns true still so the server tries to read the empty socket, causing it hang and block.

socketserver.serveforever:

```
def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
        """Handle one request at a time until shutdown.

        Polls for shutdown every poll_interval seconds. Ignores
        self.timeout. If you need to do periodic tasks, do them in
        another thread.
        """
        self.__is_shut_down.clear()
        try:
            # XXX: Consider using another file descriptor or connecting to the
            # socket to wake this up instead of polling. Polling reduces our
            # responsiveness to a shutdown request and wastes cpu at all other
            # times.
            with _ServerSelector() as selector:
                selector.register(self, selectors.EVENT_READ)  
                while not self.__shutdown_request:
                    ready = selector.select(poll_interval)
                    if ready:
                        self._handle_request_noblock()

                    self.service_actions()
        finally:
            self.__shutdown_request = False
            self.__is_shut_down.set()
```

selector.select:

```
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        def _select(self, r, w, _, timeout=None):
            r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
            return r, w + x, []
    else:
        _select = select.select

    def select(self, timeout=None):
        timeout = None if timeout is None else max(timeout, 0)
        ready = []
        try:
            r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
        except InterruptedError:
            return ready
        r = set(r)
        w = set(w)
        for fd in r | w:
            events = 0
            if fd in r:
                events |= EVENT_READ
            if fd in w:
                events |= EVENT_WRITE

            key = self._key_from_fd(fd)
            if key:
                ready.append((key, events & key.events))
        return ready
```

This is the line in `selector` that seems to be the issue. It perpetually returns a value for `r` once a GET request is received once:

`r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)`.

** EDIT1  A basic implimentatin that fails

MyServer.py

```
import http
from http import server

class Server(server.HTTPServer):
    pass
```

MyRequestHandler.py

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urllib

class OAuthGrantRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """docstring"""

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)
        self.wfile.write(
            b'<html><head><title>Authentication Status</title></head>'
            b'<body><p>The authentication flow has completed.</p>')

        print("Request handler completed")
        return
```

MyTest.py

```
import MyServer
import MyRequestHandler
import threading

def AwaitCallback(server_class=MyServer.Server,
                    handler_class=MyRequestHandler.OAuthGrantRequestHandler):
    """docstring"""

    server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    Httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    Httpd.timeout = 200
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=Httpd.serve_forever, args=(1,))

    try:
        t1.start()

    finally:

        if t1:
            t1.join()
        print("thread 3 terminated")
        if Httpd:
            Httpd.server_close()

    return 

AwaitCallback()
```

After running my test I just drop localhost:8080 into my favorite browser and wallah, the server responds successfully then locks up.

Comment: Is the problem only on windows? i.e. have you tested that the code works as expected on Linux or you don't know?

Comment: In another note to help debugging, can you `print (r)` right after select returns?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf, don't know.  I don't have a Linux machine to dev on right now.  I do believe its a Windows issue though, as the `select.select` method documentation says it calls the select method of the OS.

Comment: I can see the output, i've set up listeners.  The select.select is returning what looks like a file descriptor in r.

Comment: so, Im comparing your code to `select` example given here https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/ . Where do you actually read the data, i.e. `r.recv()` ?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf when the selector returns `ready`, `server_forever` calls `self._handle_request_noblock()`.  After passing down through many more calls we arrive in the socket module at `socket.SocketIO.readinto()` and calls the line `return self._sock.recv_into(b)` where it hangs.  After setting up lots of listeners, i'm assuming the reason it hangs here is because the socket has already been flushed.

Comment: hmm, difficult to say for me. Would be easier if you can post a minimal complete code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf, i'll try to get a basic implementation example together real quick.  But my code really doesn't matter.  Any implementation is causing this, I think it's a CPython Windows thing.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf see the implementation example.

Comment: your posted example works for me, both on win and Linux. I get `The authentication flow has completed.` in the browser.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf interesting..  I've tested in different browsers now and it seems Chrome is the culprit. I can now get the server not to hang with IE and FireFox.  Looks like Chrome forms a persistent connection that makes the selector view the socket as readable.  Still trying to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else falls in this question and has the same problem with `HTTPServer`, let's mention the new update from The Python Standard Library since version 3.7:

> class http.server.**ThreadingHTTPServer**(server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
>
> This class is identical to HTTPServer but uses threads to handle requests by using the ThreadingMixIn. This is useful to handle web browsers pre-opening sockets, on which HTTPServer would wait indefinitely.
>
> *New in version 3.7.*

Answer (score -1):

on selector.select
change

```
def _select(self, r, w, _, timeout=None):
```

into

```
def _select(self, r, w, x, timeout=None):
```